# Arraylist on android games

Tags: android, arraylist, 2d-games

I'm using an `ArrayList` on an android game to dynamically add and remove entities.

```
// This block of code runs once each 5 seconds
Entity entity = new Entity();
list.add(entity);
entity.setCallback(new Callback() {
  @Override
  public void onKill() {

    // The problem is here
    int index = list.size() - 1;
    list.remove( index );


  }
});
```

Basically I need to know the index of the added entity, in order to set a callback on it to be removed.

The problem is that entities might not die in order, so if I have

### | 0 | 1 | 2 | -key

### | a | b | c | -value

And if entity 'b', is removed, Does it reorder like

### | 0 | 1 |

### | a | c |

Or does every object keeps their own key? like

### | 0 | 2 |

### | a | c |

Otherwise, how do I fix an index to every object, knowing that each entity is added to the list automatically once each 5 second, so I think I cannot hard code `list.add(1,entity)`, but it should be done automatically? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It reorder like the first option for ArrayList. You could use regular list [] if you want it the other way around. You could also use a HashMap where you actually have a key value system...

Answer (score 0):

solved it, I just used `list.remove(entity);`